How to repeat an excel function X amount of times within the same cell
I've found a function to choose a random value from a column. This is shown in the below screenshot in cell D6.
The values in column E are product prices. As shown, column B has a "number of items added to basket". So basically what I want to do is choose X amount of random product prices, add them together, and have them shown in the value column. 'X' is the amount of items added to basket.
So for example, in cell C6, I want 2 random prices to be added together


Out of curiosity, what's the end goal of the data the formula produces? Also do you want to allow duplicates or not?

@P.b It's a fake A/B test result for a fake website, using fake products, for a very real university assignment. Duplicates are fine, I basically want the data to look like real users have purchased stuff from my fake website!

Here is one way to achieve the desired output:


=IF(B6=0,0,SUM(TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(E$6:E$19,RANDARRAY(ROWS(E$6:E$19))),2),B6,1)))


You can also spill it, with one formula:
=LET(
     δ, E6:E19, 
     MAP(B6:B20,LAMBDA(α, 
     IF(α=0,0,SUM(TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(δ,RANDARRAY(ROWS(δ))),2),α,1))))))



Thank you! First part worked like a charm :)

You can sort the price list randomly and then take the according top X values to sum them:
=LET(cntItems,B2,
prices,$E$2:$E$15,
rndSort,SORTBY(prices,RANDARRAY(ROWS(prices))),
IF(cntItems>0,SUM(TAKE(rndSort,cntItems)),0))



This formula's input parameters refer to your posted table. Place it in cell D6 and drag down.
=SUM(CHOOSEROWS(E$6:E$19,RANDARRAY(1,B6,1,ROWS(E$6:E$19),TRUE)))

This doesn't work where the value in the B column is 0!

This works the result is an Error. You can wrap it in a IFERROR(statement,0) formula.

Other approach =IF(B6=0,0,statement) which gives a flexible return value if B6=0. Can replace 0 with "Basket is empty" . This is your choice.
